# System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.ASp.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, nullreferenceexception

I have an error when i have installed the `owin` library in my project .

The error is intercepted by Application_Error in Global.asax is

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The source of this error is not Owin in the description for the error, it's my name of my project

Below the screenshot of the error:

[image]

this mistake, I receive it every time that I make a post of my login view that is displayed as a partial view in another view

thanks for help

Regards

Comment: Rather than the screenshot  maybe you can post the Code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)